# Visualizing association results after adjusting for confounders

Tags: data-visualization, confounding

I'm trying to find a way to visualize the results of an association analysis where I corrected for confounding variables.

I have a set of cytokine data (amount of protein in the blood) from a set of patients infected and uninfected with HCV. The difference between the two is minimal when we test/visualize the raw data. However, when I adjusted for things like Race, gender, age, and disease status (by building a simple linear model) the p-values improved drastically.

However, I'm having trouble finding a way to show this visually. Normally I would just show a box-plot or bee-swam plot or something similar. But the raw data is unimpressive.

Does anyone have any ideas on ways to show this beyond reporting a p-value and the confounders/effect sizes?

Comment: Perhaps something along the lines of a partial residual plot (whether in the form of a boxplot or whatever)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a trellis plot? (If you are using R, see the lattice package, for one).

Another would be to do a parallel box plot, not of the actual data but of the predicted values from the linear model.

Comment: Thanks for the Trellis plot idea. It works well here because I can keep the same units across all of the plots. I find that biologists can wrap their heads around this easier.

Answer (score 1):

If you have infected and uninfected individuals and a level of exposure (in this case Cytokine levels) you should be able to calculate a relative risk, and an appropriate 95% CI after adjustment. These can then be used in a plot that looks very similar to a boxplot if your levels are organized categorically, or a line diagram if your cytokine levels are more continuous.

For example, but with categorical levels rather than studies on the X-axis.

[image]

I'll post an example for continuous variables once I get off a train and have a working copy of R.

Comment: Interesting, and if I was showing this to a set of statisticians, mathmaticians, etc. this would certainly be a good way. But I was looking for a way that required less stats explanation. @Peter's Trellis plot is easier for a biologist to understand.